# What is the missing pattern?

Tags: pattern

What is the answer to the puzzle below and why?

[image: puzzle image]

Comment: Please, tell us first where this puzzle is excerpted from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is

> c. First figure has 1 right angle, second has 2... 4th one needs 4, which c provides.

Comment: Very nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> also C, because looking at the end of each line and whether it is the head or tail of an arrow (has an arrow head or does not), the pattern could be (2 arrow, 2 arrow + 1 tail, 3 arrow, 3 arrow + 1 tail, 4 arrow, etc)